# how do i update datetime field in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

I have a datetime field in mysql database and am trying to update just the date in phpmyadmin. However, when I run code, it just displays 0 rows affected. I just need to update the date if possible but if there is a way to also update time, that's fine.

I would grateful if someone could point out my error. Thanks

```
UPDATE boxes SET intake_date = '2017-04-20' WHERE intake_date = '2012-07-18';
```

Comment: Shouldn't you set the where clause to an id or something?

Comment: @Akin why? I am trying to update all records with that date. thanks

Comment: UPDATE boxes SET intake_date = '2017-04-20 00:00:00' WHERE intake_date = '2012-07-18';

Comment: @manish If possible, I need to leave original time and nust update the date. Thanks

Comment: Being PhpMyAdmin a graphical tool, I'd say you need to click on a table cell, edit and save :-?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Not if you have hundreds to update -)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use concat

```
UPDATE boxes SET intake_date = concat('2017-04-20 ', time(intake_date))  WHERE intake_date '2012-07-18'
```

Since the datetime format is : `Y-m-d H:i:s`, CONCAT will add the date you want(**Dont forget the space after the date**).  You add the time of the intake_date column to the `2017-04-20` and you created a datetime.

`time(intake_date)` of 2012-07-18 12:34:56 would return: 12:34:56 so you add that to 2017-04-20

Comment: Thanks for reply. However, it throws an error. should there be a = after the where? I added that and it still shows 0 rows affected. This is what i tried both with and without the space: UPDATE boxes SET intake_date = concat('2017-04-20 12:34:56 ', time(intake_date))  WHERE intake_date = '2012-07-18';

Comment: @user1532468 You're getting 0 rows effected cause the where clause should include the full column value you want. Also dont put the time in the concat. Your where clause will never succeed cause I just took the example of your question.

Comment: Then i am confused by your answer. You state: time(intake_date) of 2012-07-18 12:34:56 would return: 12:34:56 so you add that to 2017-04-20 Have I misunderstood you? Thanks

Comment: @user1532468 Yes so that means that the first parameter of CONCAT should not include the time. Like you did here: `concat('2017-04-20 12:34:56 ', time(intake_date))` should be `concat('2017-04-20 ', time(intake_date))` and your where statement should match the column you want to update

Comment: Sorry I have totally misunderstood. Could you do an edit on your answer to show exactly how it should be. Thanks

Comment: @user1532468 The code in the answer is how it should be. Except for the where statement. You have to include the time in the where statement. Then it should work.

Comment: Do you mean the time in thhe db or the time I would like to use? reason I ask I have coded as you supplied and it still says 0 rows affected. The date is definately correct. In the db you have 3 entries with the same date but different times. Have I done this correctly. Thanks UPDATE boxes SET intake_date = concat('2017-04-20 ', time(intake_date))  WHERE intake_date = '2011-08-10 12:34:56'; where the tiemtime  is the time I would like to use.

Comment: @user1532468 Yes that should be it. Dont forget to put the actual time you want to keep in the where statement and not the example I used. I just tried it and it works for me. Also dont forget the space after the date in the concat. It cant have affected 0 rows if your where statement is correct.

Comment: That is what I am trying to understand. Should the WHERE date be the date that is in the db or can it be any date I choose. If the latter, then it definately isn't working. I have checked all dates are correct, but it is still showing 0 rows affected. Question, what if I want to keep the sames times?

Comment: @user1532468 The date of the datetime you want to change should be in the where statement.. So 2012-07-18 (WITH TIME).

Comment: what if I want to keep the sames times?

Comment: @user1532468 That is how you keep the same time. This way you only change the date.

Comment: so in essence, I cannot amend the time. The where clause has to be exactly the same as the db. So what if I want to just update the date without affecting time?

Comment: @user1532468 Updating the date would be: `UPDATE boxes SET intake_date = concat(date(intake_date), 12:34:56)  WHERE intake_date= '2012-07-18 12:34:56'`

Comment: Loko The problem with that is that all the times have to be the same in all fields. They are organised same date different times. I wouldn't know what the time value was before doing the update because there are hundreds. Your method, the way I see it, means handcoding the time into a single update. There must be an alternative. Many thanks for your patience.

Comment: fyi this code worked for me. very very close to yours. UPDATE boxes SET intake_date = concat('2017-04-20 ', time(intake_date)) WHERE date(intake_date) = '2016-08-18';